# Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition - Variables Window Not Showing

Tags: visual-studio, variables, ssis

I recently installed Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. When I open up my SSIS project in this newly installed Visual Studio, I don't see my usually docked variables window. I googled this and it said to click "Variables" on the SSIS menu. I vaguely recall having to do this from time to time in my older version of Visual Studio when I would accidentally close out the variables window. But I don't see the SSIS menu in this new version of Visual Studio. I am attaching a picture of my menu bar.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Either right click in the control flow and it is in that menu:

[image]

Or with one of the SSIS packages selected it is located under the Extensions menu (Extensions -> SSIS -> Variables):

[image]

By default it will then show up under the Connection Managers at the bottom:
[image]

Comment: Ahhh. Thank you. After I posted this and much clicking around, I found you get also get to the variables by the button right of where it says "Package Explorer" in the picture I posted in my question. (I can't seem to post a new picture in this response.)